# pegar dados de uma determinada linha

Tags: jquery, tabela-html

Tenho uma tabela. Em cada linha possui um botão. Na hota que o usuário clicar, preciso pegar todos os dados dessa linha.
É uma tabela comum, onde os dados são inseridos dinamicamente, juntamente com o botão.

Esse botão tem um evento onclick que chama uma função.
Já tentei os seguintes comandos (sem sucesso)

```
function test() { // tblInfracoes
    console.log($(this).closest('tr'))
}
```

que retorna

```
w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
length: 0
prevObject: w.fn.init [Window]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

---

```
function test() {
     var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    console.log(tableData);
}
```

que retorna um vetor vazio

---

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped"  id="tbl-test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">nome</th>
            <th scope="col">idade</th>
            <th scope="col">Período de atividade</th>
            <th scope="col">Período de exclusão</th>
            <th scope="col">Opções</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Função que popula a tabela: (quero que copie os dados quando clicar em edit)

```
function insertRow(nome, idade, periodoValido, periodoInvalido) {
   var html = `
        <tr>
            <td>${nome}</td>
            <td>${idade}</td>
            <td>${periodoValido}</td>
            <td>${periodoInvalido}</td>
            <td>
                <span onclick="test()">
                      <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </span>
            </td>
         </tr>
   `;

    $("#tblInfracoes").append(html)
}
```

Comment: Você consegue colocar o código HTML de sua tabela? Pelo menos umas duas linhas é o suficiente.

Comment: `function test() {var trParent = $(this).parents("tr")[0]; console.log(trParent)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, excluindo a última coluna onde possui o botão. Você precisa passar na função o `this` do botão para poder achar a linha e suas colunas:

```js
function test(botao) {
   
   var tableData = $(botao).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").map(function(){
      return $(this).text().trim();
   }).get();

   console.log(tableData);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>
         A1
      </td>
      <td>
         B1
      </td>
      <td>
         C1
      </td>
      <td>
         <button onClick="test(this)">pegar linha</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         A2
      </td>
      <td>
         B2
      </td>
      <td>
         C2
      </td>
      <td>
         <button onClick="test(this)">pegar linha</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explicação:**

```
$(botao) // seleciona o botão clicado
.closest("tr") // busca a linha onde está o botão clicado
.find("td:not(:last-child)") // busca na linha as colunas, menos a última
```

Comment: Entendi qual foi meu erro! muito obrigada! agora consegui corrigir aqui.